Laravel Request has Empty Files
Stumped on this one.
I have a Laravel endpoint that is expected to receive an uploaded image file. The request is sent from a UI using javascript fetch. When I run the UI, I see the file being POSTed in the network tab:

But when the request is received by Laravel, there are no files. The dd prints out:

When I Log the request, it's empty. For reference, the rest of the Laravel endpoints are working as expected. Also, I have tried with and without content-type of multipart/form-data. No difference either way.
The function in Laravel is super simple right now, it's just not receiving anything:
public function imageUpload(Request $request){
    dd($request);
    if($request->file('upload')!=null):
        try{
            $file = $request->file('upload')->store('storage');
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return parent::respondWithError("Couldn't store image file.");
        }
        return response()->json([
            "status" => true,
            "message" => "File successfully uploaded",
            "file" => $file
        ]);
    else:
        return parent::respondWithError("No file present: ".json_encode($request));
    endif;
}

The JavaScript in for the UI looks like this:
const data = new FormData();
        data.append('upload', file);

        let response = fetch(api_url, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
            'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: data
          })
          .then(data => {
            return data;
        });

I've spent hours on this. Here are a few things I've ruled out:

I initially thought it was Cloudflare stripping out the file, but after bypassing Cloudflare it's the same problem.
I've tried different Content-Type headers
I've tried encoding the image as form data vs not

I've hit a wall. Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks
Mat

Is it working locally? What is the most important code, JS code? Show it to us please

I added the javascript portion above. I don't have a local build, working directly on server.

Well, don't take this as rude but only you are crazy enough to do that, hope it is not production, at least... you must try it locally, else it is going to be very difficult for you to discard what it is or is not

I have never used fetch with FormData but I think there is something wrong in there, I am used to using axios

Of course I'm not doing this in prod! :) I've read fetch has some issue with form data but in this case, I see it in the request. So a bit baffled. Maybe I'll try with axios and see if I get the same issue.

This question is similar to: How to POST with multipart/form-data header and FormData using fetch. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue was resolved by removing the Content-Type from the header of the request (though I swear I tried that previously). The request now treats the image as binary in form data and this seems to be working with Laravel's Request handler.
